# JMeter: Get response time but no Respons Data

Tags: performance, jdbc, jmeter

In JMeter is it possible to measure the duration an SQL statement takes to run against a JDBC without saving the Response data of that statement?

Background:
I want to compare two setups of a JDBC by comparing the performance.
To do that I created a few SQL statements to measure the response time with JMeter. Those SQL Statements are similar to the ones used in the program, that are connected to the JDBCs. But they return a very large number of results, which at some point always exceeds the Limit of my memory. So I want to measure the time, but not use the outcome of the SQL statement in any way. Can this be configured in JMeter?

Comment: You need to get the data to really measure the query time, because part of the processing of a query may (or will) be done when the rows get fetched. However I guess you are using MySQL Connector/J, which defaults to pulling everything over the wire before returning the first row. There are several options to use a cursor instead (setting fetchsize to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, or by setting a connection property (`useCursorFetch=true` and maybe `defaultFetchSize`).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the profile report for your database server. You will be able to find all of the details on how your queries are processed.